# How to create a custom Progress Dialog(spinner)?

Tags: android, android-spinner

[image: Sorry for the late update..but this is the kind of spinner layout I'm talking about]I have googled a lot and even gone through many of this website questions but I just can't find the solution to my problem.

I want to create a spinner like the one below. This is just a normal spinner I have done till now. I tried a variety of spinner examples but they don't give me my desired result.

Here is my code:

```
public class nextclass extends Activity {

    Thread t;
    ProgressBar dia;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MainActivity.progressDialog.dismiss();
        setContentView(R.layout.nextclassview);
    //  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // progressDialog = findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

                        new AuthenticateUserTask().execute();
                    }
                });
    }

    private class AuthenticateUserTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                    nextclass.this, "","Sucessful", true);
/*            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);

            progressDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources()
                    .getDrawable(R.layout.customspinner));
*/


            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(nextclass.this, "",
                    "Processing....", true);
            progressDialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            if (progressDialog.isShowing())
                progressDialog.dismiss();

            Intent my = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CountTime.class);
            startActivity(my);

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);![custom spinner][2]
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its known as Progress bar or Progress dialog , instead Spinner. FYI, Spinner is the combo-box like control in Android.

Comment: Sorry for the late update...but this is the custom spinner layout I'm talking about...

Answer (score 0):

I Don't have Seen any Spinner in your Code. but Anyway you can use below code for making Custom Spinner.

Inside your Layout File:

```
    <Spinnerandroid:id="@+id/spinnerview"
android:layout_width="180dp"
android:layout_height="42dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
android:background="@drawable/spinner_back"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:spinnerMode="dropdown"android:visibility="visible" />
```

inside your String.xml :

```
<string-array name="spinner_array_environtment">
        <item>Test</item>
        <item>Production</item>
    </string-array>
```

inside you Java File in OnCreate Method:

```
spinner_environment = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerview);
            adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                    R.array.spinner_array_environtment, R.layout.spinner);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner);
            spinner_environment.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Make new spinner.xml file to your layout folder :

inside spinner.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spinnerTarget"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textColor="#4C4646" />
```

Thats it!!!

Comment: read the question, he's talking about what he considers to be a spinner (the loading spinner aka Progress Bar)

Comment: @cosmincalistru this is called time wasting of a person. Bhavesh has tried a well to give answer but OP is wrong here to ask question with problem snap.

Comment: i have uploaded a image now...sorry for the delay...but i want a progress dialog like this..